# Clicking on flash in CodeIgniter is loading 404 error view page instead of the hard-coded URL in flash file

Tags: php, flash, .htaccess, codeigniter, swfobject

If I use clicktag param it works fine, but when the flash file is not using clicktag, it goes wrong and codeigniter tries (after click on the banner) load some url like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/hardcodedaddressinflash.com
```

instead of just:

```
http://hardcodedaddressinflash.com
```

If it is in plain html or php file (not using CodeIgniter) it works great.

**I guess I have to set something for swf files in codeigniter’s .htaccess to go directly where the hard-coded URL points, but how?**

Any advice?

I have tried swgobject and also direct embed swf code, but all are giving the same result.

But somehow if I am using clicktag it work fine. I do not understand at all.

**EDIT: my .htaccess file looks like this:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.

#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

#previously this would not have been possible.

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]



#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,

#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the

#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]



# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's

# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: any chance that the http:// part is missing from the hardcoded URL?

Comment: I think you are giving something like `base_url('hardcodedaddressinflash.com ')`. Just give `redirect('http://hardcodedaddressinflash.com ')`

Comment: In plain html/php (I mean outside CodeIgniter installation) it works great. I can use swfobject.js or just standard object and embed tag and it work and redirect ok. It has be something with htaccess.

Comment: It is definitely CodeIgniter issue. outside Codeigniter installation it works great

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have edited my post and added my htaccess. Could ErrorDocument 404 /index.php cause the problem or is there a way to set flash files be loaded not using codeigniter controllers at all?

Comment: Any advice how to fix my htaccess?

Comment: Anybody ever experienced this kind of problem in CodeIgniter?